# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$ converges almost surely implies the following property

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_{n}$ : random variables.
Define a stopping time $$N_c=\inf\{n\geq1:|S_{n}|>c\}.$$where
$S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$.

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}$ converges almost surely, is this implying : 
there exists $c>0$ such that $$N_c=\infty  \text{ a.s}?$$

Comment: Where you find this definition  ?$$\inf\{n\geq1:|S_{n}|>c\}=\infty$$ Is it originated from special article ,or book ?

Comment: @Khosrotash I edited! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Note that for any $c>0$,
$$
P(N_c<\infty)\geq P(N_c=1)=P(\lvert X_1\rvert>c).
$$
So, unless there exists $c>0$ such that $\lvert X_1\rvert\leq c$ almost surely, it cannot be the case that $c>0$ exists such that $N_c=\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Actually $|X_n| \leq K$ for some nonrandom constant $K>0$. Can we get the above result?

Comment: Nope.  Take $X_n=rX_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 2$, $r\in(0,1)$. Then given $X_1$, the series converges to $\frac{X_1}{1-r}$, which grows without bound as you choose $r$ closer and closer to $0$.  So, generate a series as follows: $X_1=K$; let $R$ be uniformly chosen from $(0,1)$; and let $X_n=RX_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 2$.  This satisfies $\lvert X_n\rvert\leq K$ for all $n$, and almost-sure convergence, but still cannot be uniformly bounded.